# Formatting Floating point numbers in android Java

Tags: java, android, string-formatting, decimalformat

I want to format a floating number into a String in following pattern

`X.XX`  -> when there is only 1 digit before decimal then 2 decimal precision

`XX.XX`  -> when there are 2 digits before decimal then 2 decimal precision

`XXX.X`  -> when there are 3 digits before decimal then 1 decimal precision

`XXXX..`  -> when there are 4 or more digits before decimal then no decimal points should be displayed

How to do this in Java?

Comment: What you tried for this?

Comment: Is this your homework ? because I cant see what you have tried

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: @Mohit Its not a Homework.
I read DecimalFormat and StringFormat Documentation of java but I am not able to decide how should I format them in order to get the above behaviour. As in the last case I dont want to show the decimal values . How to achieve that case

Comment: Have you looked at the [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: @DillonRyanRedding .. Yes I have read that. But I am not able to use that to perfectly fulfil my requirement. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simple code using [Decimal Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) can be helpful

```
float f=  24.56f;//Replace with your float number
    int i = (int)f;
    if(i<100)
        System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(f));//This functions will round the last bits also i.e. greater then 4 will increase the number preceding also 
    else if( i < 1000)
        System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(f));
    else 
        System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#").format(f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have float **f** number

```
float f;
int a = (int) f;
String res = null;
if (a<100) res = String.format("%.2f");
else if (a<1000) res = String.format("%.1f");
else res = String.valueOf(a);
```